# Ax 2012 order WMSLocationId

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I would order the WorkLine belonging to different WorkId based on WMSLocationId
Example:

```
Work 1
workLine1.1: wmsLocation: 0201
workLine1.2: wmsLocation: 0202

Work2:
workLine2.1: wmsLocation: 2002170200
workLine2.2: wmsLocation: 2002170201
workLine2.3: wmsLocation: 0203
```

I want a list like this:

```
position 1) workLine2.1: wmsLocation: 2002170200
position 2) workLine2.2: wmsLocation: 2002170201
position 3) workLine1.1: wmsLocation: 0201
position 4) workLine1.2: wmsLocation: 0202
position 5) workLine2.3: wmsLocation: 0203
```

There are a function that sort the wmsLocationId?

Comment: Do you have any code you're working with?

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is just basic querying and there are many ways to solve it.  Here is a sample job that appears to do what you want:

```
WHSWorkLine     workLine;
int             i;

while select workLine
    order by WMSLocationId asc, WorkId asc, LineNum asc
{
    i++;
    info(strFmt("position %1) workLine %2.%3, wmsLocation: %4", i, workLine.WorkId, workLine.LineNum, workLine.WMSLocationId));
}
```

See the following links for different querying methods:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa656402.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa638454.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb314753.aspx